# Why is a (virtual) device necessary for a unit test based on ActivityUnitTestCase?

Tags: android, eclipse, unit-testing, junit

I want to write a simple unit test based on android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase. As the test is simple I expect a very short execution time. But the test takes at least 6 seconds.

The test tests a simple application from Google's tutorial. This is my test:

```
public class MainActivityUnitTest extends ActivityUnitTestCase<MainActivity> {

    public MainActivityUnitTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(),
                MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent, null, null);
    }

    public void testNextActivityWasLaunchedWithIntent() {
        Button sendButton =
                (Button) getActivity()
                .findViewById(com.bjoerne.aroundtheworldvisualizer.R.id.send);
        sendButton.performClick();

        Intent intent = getStartedActivityIntent();
        assertNotNull("Intent was null", intent);
        final String payload =
                intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        assertEquals("", payload);
    }
}
```

I chose "Run as -> Android JUnit Test" in Eclipse. Is that correct? But then an android virtual device (AVD) seems to be necessary. If the AVD has not been started it's started for the test (and the test takes a minute). But even if the AVD is already running it seems to be checked or initialized before the test is executed which takes a few seconds.

I don't need a running AVD for a ActivityUnitTestCase, do I? Is there a way to accelerate the test execution?

Answer (score 1):

You need some sort of device in which to run the test. An Android JUnit test is an Android app, and an Android app needs the Android system in which to run. An Android test doesn't run in the VM of your workstation, it has to run in an Android VM. To run a test in an Android VM, you have to install it in an Android environment. One way to run the test is to install the test on an Android physical device. Another way to run the test is to create an AVD, which is the configuration for the Android emulator, and then run the test in the emulator.

The time lag you're seeing may be the delay in the emulator starting up. Once it's started, running the test again may be faster, but not as fast as running the test on a real device.

Comment: These "unit" tests don't test a unit in isolation; they test all of Android. Always start your work day by starting an AVD, first. Once it's up, use Package Explorer -> MyTests -> Context Menu ("right" mouse button) -> Debug As -> Debug Configurations -> Target -> "Always Prompt..." -> Debug. When the Android Device Chooser comes up, select the running AVD, and click "Use same device for future launches". THEN, as you TDD, Ctrl+Tab to the *Test.java file, and tap F11 to re-launch the last configured run. This is the fastest (ahem) TDD cycle possible...

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the unit test concepts provided by Android. I expected that there is a way to write tests without a (virtual) device.

I guess that [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) is what I was looking for. It provided the same API as Android does, but without a device. The device is mocked. People who want to develop test-driven may want to check this out.